# Understanding proof of the Lemma 7.42 in the Gortz's Algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, p.195, Lemma 7.42 and trying to understand some statements :

[image]

( **Note (Errata)** : In the proof, $A'^{r} \to M'$ is more correct instead of $A'^{n} \to M'$ and $ A_s^{r} \cong M_s$ is more correct instead of $A_s^{r}\cong M_s^{r}$. )

Throughout question, we will use the Corollary 7.41 (i) => (ii) in the above image.

**First**, for the second underlined statement, can we prove even "freeness of $M' = S^{-1}M$ of rank $r$", instead of the "local freeness of rank $r$"? Reason that I claim this is, since $M'$ is viewed as an $A'$-module and $A'$ is a semi-local ring, we may apply the answer of 'wxu' in next linked question : [How can I find an element $x\not\in\mathfrak mM_{\mathfrak m}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150944/how-can-i-find-an-element-x-not-in-mathfrak-mm-mathfrak-m-for-every-maximal) ? Is there something that I'm mistaken? If we can show the freeness of $M'$ (of rank $r$), then we can use [A surjective homomorphism between finite free modules of the same rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153516/a-surjective-homomorphism-between-finite-free-modules-of-the-same-rank) to show that $A'^{r} \to M'$ is an isomorphism.

Or if not, is there any other method to show that $A'^{r}\to M'$ is isomorphism just from the local freeness of $M'$ of rank $r$?

**Second**. let's see the first underlined statement. Assume that we can prove that $M'$ is free over $A'$ of rank $r$. Then even if this statement is true, doesn't it guarantee the freeness of $M'/\tau M'$ over $A'/\tau $?  So he detours through noting that "$A'/\tau$ is a product of fields" and shows the freeness of $M'/\tau M'$? (c.f. [Every $A$-module is projective if and only if $A$ is a finite direct product of fields.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814005/every-a-module-is-projective-if-and-only-if-a-is-a-finite-direct-product-of) )

**Thrid**, for the final underliend statement, at last, we have an isomorphism $(S^{-1}A)^{r} = A'^{r} \xrightarrow{\cong} M' = (S^{-1}M)$ Form this, how to show the existence of $s \in S$ and an isomorphism $A_s^{r} \xrightarrow{\cong} M_s$? Proposition 7.27 in the proof is as follows :

[image]

Thanks for reading. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is correct, but note that Gortz is basically redoing wxu’s answer. (You also need to see that $M’$ is projective, but it’s a tensor product of $M$ which is flat of finite presentation).
2. Yes, but same thing: this is the first step of wxu’s approach anyway.
3. Because $M$ is of finite presentation, you can multiply your isomorphism $(S^{-1}A)^r \rightarrow S^{-1}M$ by a fixed $s \in S$ so that it comes from a map $g: A^r \rightarrow M$. Because localization is exact, you know that $S^{-1}\ker{g}=S^{-1}\operatorname{coker}{g}=0$. Since $\operatorname{coker}{g}$ is finitely generated, there is some $t \in S$ such that $t\operatorname{coker}{g}=0$, thus $g_t: (A_t)^r \rightarrow M_t$ is onto; as $M_t$ has finite presentation, it follows that $\ker{g_t}$ is finitely generated and such that $S^{-1}\ker{g_t}=0$. Thus there is some $s \in S$ such that $s\ker{g_t}=0$ (over $A_t$). Thus the kernel and cokernel of $g: A_{st}^r \rightarrow M_{st}$ is zero, hence this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: O.K. Thank you. For 3, can I ask question? :) 1) How can we choose $g:A^{r} \to M$ such that $S^{-1}g$ becomes the isomorphism $(S^{-1}A)^{r} \to S^{-1}M$, from the condition that $M$ is of finite presentation?  2) What the map $g_t : (A_t)^{r} \to M_t$ means exactly ?   3) Why $S^{-1}\operatorname{ker}g_t =0$? I guess that this can be deduced from $S^{-1}\operatorname{ker}g=0$. And how..  4) Why the kernel and cokernel of $g_{st} : A_{st}^{r} \to M_{st}$ is zero? By the direct proof?

Comment: 1) let $f$ be the original map $(A’)^r \rightarrow M’$. For each $1 \leq i \leq r$, $f(e_i)$ can be written as $m_i/s_i$ with $m_i \in M$, $s_i \in S$. So define $g: A^r \rightarrow M$ such that $g(e_i)=\prod_{j \neq i}{s_j} \cdot m_i$, then $g/(s_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot s_r)$ is exactly (after localization by $S$) $f$. I was going about this the wrong way, we don’t need any assumption on $M$ for this.

Comment: 2) the localization of $g$ at $t$. 3) $\ker{g_t}$ is exactly the set of $m/t^r$ with $r \geq 0$ and $m \in \ker{g}$. 4) they’re localizations at $st$ of the kernel and cokernel of $g$, and $s,t$ have been constructed so that these localizations vanish.

Comment: For $g_t$, it seems that more correct notation is $(A^{r})_t \to M_t$, instead of $(A_t)^{r} \to M_t$. Isn't that right?

Comment: Uhm.. and for the comment for 1), what the notation $g/(s_1, \cdots , s_r)$ exactly means?~~

Comment: Anyway, I will try to fill in the details of the proof !

Comment: First comment: if you want. Second comment: just multiply $g$ by $\left(\prod_i{s_i}\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: C.f. After some investigation, I think that more correct statement(not involving the multiplicaion of $g$ by $(\prod_i s_i)^{-1}$ ) is, $f=(S^{-1}g) \circ \psi$, where $\psi : (A')^{r}=(S^{-1}A)^{r} \to S^{-1}(A^{r})$ is the canonical isomorphism. (We can provide its explicit form : $(a_1/s_1 , \cdots a_r/s_r) \mapsto (a_1s_2s_3\cdots s_r, \cdots ,a_rs_1s_2\cdots s_{r-1})/(s_1s_2 \cdots s_r)$ ) :) Anyway thank you.